# Facebook Graph API Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a score on facebook using graph api for a game that i created. My input is the following:

Method is POST:

```
me/score/score=10

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) At least one reference object must be specified.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Aa4wSne7KqK"
  }
}
```

I was able to do it yesterday, and the score changed to 100. However it is not working today.

If i use the get method to see my score, here is what i get:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "score": 100,
      "user": {
        "name": "Nassif Bousaba",
        "id": "10159173554635214"
      }
    },
    {
      "score": 0,
      "user": {
        "name": "Nassif Bousaba",
        "id": "10159173554635214"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All permissions were granted since i was able to post the score before.

Comment: `me/score/score=10` - please explain what that is supposed to be.

Comment: POST in id=me, get score list and update variable score to be equal to 10 @CBroe

Comment: That’s not how POST parameters work.

Comment: @CBroe and how does it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after changing the code from request ExecuteAndWait to executeAsync. Additionally i had to change the application type to game in facebook application settings. Code is below for android

```
public void PublishMyScore(String Score)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("score", Score);


    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/"+AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()+"/scores/",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.w("TAG","SCORE ADDED");
                    Log.w("TAG",response.toString());
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
```